# How to post with specific content type in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, captions

Is there a way to POST a specific Content-type using Zend GData? Specifically I want to post a file with type

```
"Content-Type: application/vnd.youtube.timedtext; charset=UTF-8"
```

Otherwise, will I need to use cURL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the specific content type of your file with `setContentType()` with something like this:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);

$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('your_file.ext');
// content type you want to use
$filesource->setContentType('application/vnd.youtube.timedtext; charset=UTF-8');
```

There is good example with more options at [Zend Framework: Documentation: Using the YouTube Data API - Zend Framework Manual : Uploading Videos to YouTube](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html#zend.gdata.youtube.uploads).